# jQuery .css() not applying to newly created CSS classes

Tags: jquery, css

I feel like this may be due to basic mis-understandings but I can't for the life of me get this to work.

I have a list of items in a view and I want to be able to tick a **checkbox** to change the way the view appears. This works perfectly with the code I have except when you move to "Page 2" using my **JSON** code (no page reloads).

The newly created elements on "Page 2" ignore my code even though my **checkbox** remains ticked.

This is my checkbox code:

```
function smallCards(){


if (jQuery('input.smallcheck').is(':checked')) {

    jQuery("#card-list").css("display", "inline-grid"); 
    jQuery("#card-list").css("width", "500px"); 
    jQuery(".card-info").css("display", "contents");
    jQuery("figure").css("float", "left");

   //jQuery(".votes").css("font-size", "10px"); 
   //jQuery("#card-list img").css("height", "138"); 
   //jQuery("#card-list img").css("width", "97"); 


  }

}
```

The first two work `#card-list` but `.card-info` and `figure` don't seem to be applying to the newly created "**page 2**" elements.

There is then Jquery code that runs a JSON callback to generate each item on the page (including pagination for all the pages).

This is a small sample of the code:

```
    jQuery.getJSON('https://www.example.com/getlist.php?sortby='+sortby+'&attrib='+attrib+'&ban='+ban+'&cardset='+cardset+'&type='+type+'&name='+name+'&level='+level+'&race='+race+'&page='+pgno+'&callback=?',
        function (data) {
            host = "https://www.example.com/pics/";

            jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

htmlst += '<div id="container"><figure><a data-name="' + val.name + '" onClick="mainsearch(' + val.id + ')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="' + host + val.id + '.jpg"></a><figcaption style="line-height:4px;"><div id="votes" class="votes"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" title="Times Searched" alt="Times Searched" style="color: #0d0d0d;"></i> '+ReplaceNumberWithCommas(val.times)+'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="u'+val.id+'" onclick="voteuplist(this)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" title="Upvote" alt="Upvote" style="color: #FF8b60;"></i> '+val.rating_up+'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="d'+val.id+'" onclick="votedownlist(this)" style="color: #9494FF;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" title="Downvote" alt="Downvote" style="color: #9494FF;"></i> '+val.rating_down+'</a></div></figcaption></figure>  <div class="card-info"><div class="card-name">'+val.name+'</div><div class="card-desc"></div></div></div>';
```

When I generate the second page (which uses the above JSON function) it will ignore my checkbox settings. Even if I run `smallCards()` at the end of the above function.

Sorry for the lack of detail. This was built ages for me as a service and I've been trying to enhance it myself for a few months now.

Comment: "newly created" as in did they get added after you ran the above script or before?  Please create a [MCVE] showing your problem

Comment: Are you re-running your checkbox code after you load your new content?  It only applies to the elements that exist at the time it runs.

Comment: Hey Freedomn-m. I tried running the checkbox function smallCards() at the end of my code that generates the second page but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. I have to un-tick and then re-tick the checkbox manually. I'll update the OP with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing a ajax request so you need to call the css once again after the ajax has completed

```
 jQuery.getJSON('https://www.example.com/getlist.php?sortby='+sortby+'&attrib='+attrib+'&ban='+ban+'&cardset='+cardset+'&type='+type+'&name='+name+'&level='+level+'&race='+race+'&page='+pgno+'&callback=?',
    function (data) {

//...
if (jQuery('input.smallcheck').is(':checked')) {

    jQuery("#card-list").css("display", "inline-grid");  //Default has no display set
    jQuery("#card-list").css("width", "500px");          //Default has no width set
    jQuery(".card-info").css("display", "contents");     //Default is Display:None 
    jQuery("figure").css("float", "left");               //Default is no float
  }
}});
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Feeling really foolish but I'm still trying to learn all of this. Thanks!!

Comment: ajax add the content after you call the css functions so the styles doesn't update

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. That makes sense now. That's why card-list works, because it already exists and isn't being regenerated by ajax.